# Conditional probability(component network)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Suppose the diagram of an electrical system is as given in the following picture:
[image]

Lets assume that the probability that any given component works is independent with probability **P**. meaning that not working component probability is ***1-P***.
I found that the probability that the system is working(signal from A <-> B) is $$F=P^2(P+P^2-P^3)(3P-3P^2+P^3)$$

im trying to find the probability that: knowing the system is working what is the probability that at least one of the components ***5\7*** not working.

**(a)** i tried doing it using $P(not(5)\cup not(7)|F)$. but im not sure if i did it correctly so ive tried doing it this way:
**(b)** i calculated the probabilty that **5 is not working and the system does** added the probabilty that **7 is not working and the system does**, added the probability that **5and7 not working but the system does**.

ive got two diffent answers, im wondering if what i did on **(b)** is wrong and why or maybe i made i mistake when solving like **(a)**

Comment: In (b), when you were calculating P(5 not working | system works), did you take into account that 7 works?

Comment: yes, im just wondering if its correct to do so , if it is i guess my (a) is the problem

Comment: Yes, your idea is correct. $F$ is also correct.